# Using windows as wifi hotspot with multiple access passwords

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, hotspot, wireless-hotspot

I want to configure my computer as a wifi hotspot (Windows)

I'm aware that i can do that using: netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=Hotspotname key=password .

But what i actually want, is a kind of user access system, where i can provide for example 30 minutes of hotspot use to a specific person.

Basically i thought about creating multiple passwords (one for each person) and configuring the hotspot to accept connections using multiple passwords.

Is it possible ? if not, any other proposition is welcomed.

PS: Will program this later in a programming langage and use OS calls.

Comment: Windows does not do this. You need a third party wireless app, and the ones I have seen are Browser-based

Comment: I want to this "wireless app", i will handle password generation / user creation with my software, i just need a correspondance way to tell windows to not accept this "person", perhaps with its MAC Adress or something else...